# Revenue based AB test

Tags: ab-test, zero-inflation

I have preformed an AB test on revenues (as my target is to increase revenues). 
Two groups of users were offered with a different marketing offer which in group A (Blue) led to a higher conversion rates, but on group B (Orange) led to a higher average revenues per user.
As can be described here : [image]

[image]
Trying to statistically determine which offer is better, leads to no significant conclusion since using a t test has a high variance (since most of my data is 0) so that the means are insignificantly different.
I am looking for a statistical test, or to be more specific, a R package that can calculate and determine which group has better revenues.